# Selecting a row interval according to a Column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-slicing

Hi everyone I have a dataset that looks like this

```
transferid   value     type 
  5545        100       X
  5123        40        A
  5566        35        A
  5675        700       X
  5235        1100      A
  5616        350       A
  5772        170       X
```

it has it index for any purposes and what I would like to do is to slice the data set in rows, generating a new dataset like this one

```
df1=
transferid   value     type 
  5545        100       X
  5123        40        A
  5566        35        A
  5675        700       X

df2=
transferid   value     type 
  5675        700       X
  5235        1100      A
  5616        350       A
  5772        170       X
```

including the values like this. Is there a possibility to do this on a single slicing? I tried gathering the indexes and using df.loc to set the slicing intervals, but I haven't had any success with this approach. The dataset could start with any type of transfer but I need to slice between and every time it finds a transfer type X and if it finds no other type X at the end, slice till the end.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
i = np.where(df.type == "X")[0]
pd.concat({j: df.iloc[x:y] for j, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(i, i[1:] + 1))})

     transferid  value type
0 0        5545    100    X
  1        5123     40    A
  2        5566     35    A
  3        5675    700    X
1 3        5675    700    X
  4        5235   1100    A
  5        5616    350    A
  6        5772    170    X
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although what I actually needed was to get the intervals in a workable array so I can slice and write in different csv. Your first line of code worked like a charm for my purpose